# moving a sprite while holding down a key not working

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

So im trying the make my sprite move constantly when im holding my arrow keys, but i need to keep pressing it to move it. any idea why?
here's my code:

yes i have imported pygame and everything

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color = blue,widht = 64, height = 64):

        super(Block, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((widht, height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("2dSounds/Walk.wav")

        self.hspeed = 0
        self.vspeed = 0
```

to update the sprite, so it changes places depending what key i press

```
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.hspeed
        self.rect.y += self.vspeed
```

to change the speed using a_block.change_speed(...)

```
    def change_speed(self, hspeed, vspeed):
        self.hspeed += hspeed
        self.vspeed += vspeed
```

to set the position of the sprite when i first create it

```
    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x 
        self.rect.y = y
```

to set a image for my sprite i just created

```
    def set_image(self, filename = None):
        if(filename != None):
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

to play a sound

```
    def play_sound():
        self.sound.play()
```

the gameloop

```
def game_loop():    
    a_block  = Block()

    global event


    gameDisplay.fill(white)

#Quit

    gameExit = False



    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
```

the controls that dont work

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    a_block.change_speed(-20, 0)            
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    a_block.change_speed(20, 0) 
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    a_block.change_speed(0, -20)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    a_block.change_speed(0, 20) 
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    a_block.change_speed(0, 0)          
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    a_block.change_speed(0, 0)  
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    a_block.change_speed(0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    a_block.change_speed(0, 0)
```

To draw a_block and other things

```
        block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        a_block.set_image('2dImages/brick.png')
        a_block.set_position(display_width/2, display_height/2)
        a_block.update()
        block_group.add(a_block)

        block_group.draw(gameDisplay)
```

update display

```
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

thanks alot in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of your code (but after you call `pygame.init()`), add the following line of code:

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(10)
```

This will post keyboard events to the event queue every 10 milliseconds even if the key was already pressed.

Comment: OMG THIS WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! :D HAVE BEEN STRUGGLING WITH THIS FOR HOURS!!!

Comment: If this worked for you and you think others might want to see this answer, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick outline.

Comment: i accepted it because i think this will help others, i searched pretty long on this website and other websites but never found an answer. thank you so much again! :)

Comment: The documentation for this can be found at https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html